# Getting a crash when switching to section

Tags: batch-file

Im working on a text based game and I am getting a crash when I type 1. 2 works fine, I have tried redirecting 1 to the first section of my batch file and it still crashes. I am very confused.

EDIT: Thank you for the answers unfortunately I was just stupid. I was editing a backup of my program yesterday instead of the main program. Hence There was no existing target for choice 1 at that point. Oops.

Comment: Consider using the `choice` command. See `choice /?` for help. Run your script without `echo off` to see exactly what happens. Run it from within an already open cmd window (not with a mouseclick) to keep the window open and read the errormessage(s).

Comment: I'll try running it within a separate window tomorrow. It's just odd because I use the exact same format in two other places in my program and it runs fine. I've tried keeping echo on and adding a pause command but it still crashes. I have a feeling it's going to be the dumbest little thing I've missed somewhere

Comment: the most likely reason for the crash if option 2 is working is that the label `test` is not present in your script

Comment: Single quotes have no special meaning in batch scripting, so `if '%choice%' =='1'` should be changed to `if "%choice%" == "1"`. You may not think it's important, and it may have nothing to do with your reported issue, but you have absolutely no control over the input of the end user. The problem with the `SET /P` command is that your end user is free to input nothing, or anything at all, including problematic characters, and malicious code. _If you think that the end user will only enter `1` or `2`, you are crazy, the first rule of programming is that the end user will try to break your code_.

Answer (score 0):

As per stephans comment, the `choice` command is best suited for menu input.
Menus can be built dynamically by using a macro or function to assign a list of options to an array for selection using the index of the choice key pressed. Here is an exmaple of doing so:

```bat
==================================================================
@Echo off
:# [Menu] Macro Author: T3RRY = Version: 1.0.5
:# Supports Coloring of menu on Windows 10 If virtual Terminal sequences enabled.
:# IMPORTANT - RESERVED VARIABLES: \n [Menu]*
:#  - [Menu] macro variables prefixed with [Menu] to avoid potential conflict with other script variables.
:#  - \n is a standard definition of an escaped linefeed for creating multiline Macro variables.

:# Menu macro escaped for Definition with DelayedExpansion Enabled. Ensures correct Environment:
 If not "!" == "" (
  Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
 )

:# WinVersion Test. Assigns flag true if system is windows 10. Used to apply color with Virtual terminal codes.
 Set "[menu]Win10="
 Ver | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:" 10." > nul && Set "[menu]Win10=true"

:# Test if virtual terminal codes enabled ; enable if false
:# removes [menu]win10 flag definition if version does not support Virtual Terminal sequences
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Reg Query HKCU\Console | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"VirtualTerminalLevel    REG_DWORD    0x1" > nul || (
    Reg Add HKCU\Console /f /v VirtualTerminalLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 1
  ) > Nul || Set "[menu]Win10="
 )

(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify. =%)

:# Key index list Allows maximum 36 menu options [ 0 indexed ]. Component of Menu Macro
 Set "[menu]Key_List=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

:# Get console width for dividing line
 Cls & mode 120,40
 for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"Columns"`) do Set /A "[menu]Console_Width=%%W"

:# Build Menu option color array [ RGB colormix ; red biased scaling darker. ]
 If defined [menu]Win10 For /F %%E in ('Echo prompt $E^|cmd')Do Set "\E=%%E"

 Set "[menu]i=0"
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[Menu]Color_Off=%\E%[0m"
  For /L %%i in (232 -4 96)Do (
   Set /A "[menu]BB=(%%i/4)+50,[menu]GG=%%i-[menu]BB,[menu]RR=[menu]GG+[menu]BB+(%%i/2)"
   Set "[menu]Color[![menu]i!]=%\E%[38;2;![menu]RR!;![menu]GG!;![menu]BB!m"
   Set /A [menu]i+=1
 ))
 Set "[menu]i="

:# Define highlight color to use for a selected option
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Highlight_Color=%\E%[0m%\E%[48;2;50;150;200m%\E%[31m%\E%[K"
 )

:# Assign Flag true to enable Highlighting of selected option.
:# - Clears screen before menu is output in order to count line position of options.
:# - Highlight will only be seen if the screen output is visible for a noticible length of time after
:# - expansion of the [Menu] macro. Use 'Pause', 'Timeout' or another method of effecting a delay if the screen buffer
:# - will be refreshed or scrolled by subsequent output immediately after menu selection to allow highlight to be seen.
:# - If not defined as true, screen will not be cleared prior to menu output and selection will not be highlighted.
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Highlight=true"
 )

:# Force console line dimensions to a size that supports highlight mode by preventing buffer scroll
 If /I "%[menu]Highlight%" == "true" (
  for /F "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LIC:"Lines"`) do If %%W LSS 40 Mode ![menu]Console_Width!,40
 )

:# Build dividing line for menu output.
 Set "[menu]Divider=" & For /L %%i in (2 1 %[menu]Console_Width%)Do Set "[menu]Divider=![menu]Divider!-"

:# Define dividing line Color
 If defined [menu]Win10 (
  Set "[menu]Divider=%\E%[33m%\E%[4m![menu]Divider!%\E%[0m"
 )

:# Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
:# Supports 36 options [ options are zero indexed ]

     Set [Menu]=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Clear screen if highlight flag true  =%  If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" CLS%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^![menu]Divider^^!%\n%
%= Reset Index value for Opt[#]         =%  Set "[menu]Index=0"%\n%
%= Undefine choice option key list      =%  Set "[menu]Choice_Keys="%\n%
%= For Each in list;                    =%  For %%G in (^^![menu]Options^^!)Do If not ^^![menu]Index^^! GTR 35 (%\n%
%= For Option Index value               =%   For %%i in (^^![menu]Index^^!)Do (%\n%
%= Build the Choice key list and Opt[#] =%    Set "[menu]Choice_Keys=^![menu]Choice_Keys^!^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!"%\n%
%= arrays using the character at the    =%    Set "[menu]Opt[^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!]=%%~G"%\n%
%= current substring index.             =%    Set "[menu]Option_Output=%%~G"%\n%
%= Display ; removing # variable prefix =%    Echo(^^![menu]Color[%%i]^^![^^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^^!] ^^![menu]Option_Output:#=^^!![menu]Color_Off!%\n%
%= Store line number of options         =%    Set "[menu]Line#^![menu]Key_List:~%%i,1^!=%%i"%\n%
%= Increment Opt[#] Index var 'Index'   =%    Set /A "[menu]Index+=1"%\n%
%= Close Index loop                     =%   )%\n%
%= Close Options loop                   =%  )%\n%
%= Output Dividing Line                 =%  Echo(^^![menu]Divider^^!%\n%
%= Select option by character index     =%  For /F "Delims=" %%o in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\Choice.exe /N /C:^^![menu]Choice_Keys^^!')Do (%\n%
%= Assign return var '[menu]Selection'  =%   Set "[menu]Selection=^![menu]Opt[%%o]^!"%\n%
%= Highlight selected option with Line# =%   If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" (For /F "Delims=" %%X in ("^![menu]Line#%%o^!")Do For /F "Delims=" %%Y in ('Set /A "%%X+2"')Do Echo(%\E%[%%Y;1H^^![menu]Highlight_Color^^!{^^![menu]Key_List:~%%X,1^^!} ^^![menu]Opt[%%o]^^!![menu]Color_Off!)%\n%
%= value selected from Opt[#] array.    =%   If /I "^![menu]Selection^!" == "Exit"   CLS ^& Exit /B 2%\n%
%= Exit type determines Errorlevel.     =%   If /I "^![menu]Selection^!" == "Previous" CLS ^& Exit /B 1%\n%
%= Return to previous script on Exit    =%  )%\n%
%= Move cursor to end of menu field     =%  If /I "^![menu]Highlight^!" == "true" For /F "Delims=" %%Y in ('Set /A [menu]Index + 2')Do Echo(%\E%[%%Y;1H%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List   =% )Else Set [menu]Options=
========================================== :# End Definition of Menu Macro

:# Usage example
:Menu
 %[Menu]% Exit Demo list of options to select from. Each Displayed with different color tone and index key for selecting the desired choice. "Doublequote multiword options"

:# Selected option returned in '[menu]Selection' variable. 
 Echo(^> ![menu]Selection!
 Pause > nul
Goto :Menu
```

The above type of approach makes scripting multiple menus very simple. Just expand the macro with the list of permitted options and assess the value of the `[Menu]Selection` variable to determine what action to take.